# pandas conditional group-by and count values

Tags: pandas, group-by, count, nested, conditional-statements

I want to count the number of 'bb' Value corresponding to 'b' Label for the same 'aa' Value of 'a' Label. It is the simplified version of the problem.

For instance the number of 'Python' Value corresponding to 'Computer Skill' when the job title is programmer ('aa' Value for Job as 'a' Label).

I run the following code but it doesn't work, right. The results should be 2 'bb' corresponding to 2 'aa'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data= {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
   'Label':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'], 
   'Values':['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'bbb', 'cc'] 
     } 
dataset=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
d=dataset.groupby(by=['Label'])
for k, value in d: 
      print(value[value.Label=='a'].groupby('Values').count())
```

Comment: In the inner loop you filter only to Label='a'. If you define the logic to match between label and values it would be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data= {'id':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
   'Label':['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
   'Values':['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'cc', 'aa', 'bb', 'bbb', 'cc']
     }
dataset=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
d=dataset.groupby(by=['Label'])
for k, value in d:
    print(value.loc[value.Label=='a','Values'].value_counts())
```

Comment: It is exactly return the previous results. I want to get number of 'bb' values.

Comment: I think I don't understand exactly what you want to do then. Would you mind to give an other example?